# Devel::Declare removes line from script

Tags: perl, declare

I am trying to learn [`Devel::Declare`](http://p3rl.org/Devel%3a%3aDeclare) so as to attempt to reimplement something like `PDL::NiceSlice` without source filters. I was getting somewhere when I noticed that it was removing the next line from my script. To illustrate I have made this minimal example wherein one can use the `comment` keyword to remove the entire line from the code, allowing a compile even though barewords abound on that line.

```
#Comment.pm
package Comment;

use strict;
use warnings;

use Devel::Declare ();

sub import {
  my $class = shift;
  my $caller = caller;

  Devel::Declare->setup_for(
      $caller,
      { comment => { const => \&parser } }
  );
  no strict 'refs';
  *{$caller.'::comment'} = sub {};

}

sub parser {
  #my $linestr = Devel::Declare::get_linestr;
  #print $linestr;

  Devel::Declare::set_linestr("");
}

1
```

and

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
#test.pl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Comment;

comment stuff;

print "Print 1\n";
print "Print 2\n";
```

yields only

```
Print 2
```

what am I missing?

P.S. I will probably have a few more questions on `D::D` coming up if I should figure this one out, so thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok so I got it. Using `perl -MO=Deparse test.pl` you get:

```
use Comment;
use warnings;
use strict 'refs';
comment("Print 1\n");
print "Print 2\n";
test.pl syntax OK
```

which tells me that if forces the `comment` function to be called. After some experimentation I found that I could just set the output to call `comment()` explicitly so that it doesn't try to call `comment` on whatever is next.

```
sub parser {
  Devel::Declare::set_linestr("comment();");
}
```

so that the deparse is:

```
use Comment;
use warnings;
use strict 'refs';
comment();
print "Print 1\n";
print "Print 2\n";
test.pl syntax OK
```

and the proper output too.